# How can I export sublayers to png in Adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, export, png

A designer did a design for me.  It is in Adobe illustrator.  In order to write my program, I need to export sublayers one by one to `.png` files.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is by using a script. I created a pretty powerful script recently and blogged about it here:

http://www.arcticmill.com/2012/08/export-layers-as-png-files-from-illustrator-in-multiple-resolutions.html

The blog post contains the script and instructions on how to use the script (and also modify it if you want to).

Hope it helps!
/Johan

Comment: **EXCELLENT** script Johan. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I managed to discover that awesome script some weeks ago, but nowdays the site throws a 404 error. It's a shame because the script is super useful. I wonder if it just dissapear or if they moved their article somewhere else or something...

Comment: Please share the new URL or a google doc file link for the script, existing URL is throwing 404

Answer (score 1):

It actually it may be easier to export the .ai file to a Photoshop file, then use Photoshop to export (`Save for Web`) to .png file format.

Within Ai, you'll have to turn visibility off for every layer/sublayer other than the sublayer you want to save. And then turn on another sub layer and repeat until all files have been exported. There's no automated way built into Illustrator to export or save layers (or sublayers) as individual files.

However, if you export the .ai file as a .psd with layers in tact (assuming there's no transparency or blending modes used in AI), Photoshop does offer scripts or automated ways to export layers as files.

In the end, it really all depends upon the artwork. Some Ai art exports to .psd file format just fine, other Ai art takes some tweaking, which may or may not be feasible for a given project.